# how to remove trailing non-alpha characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
import re

s = 'Sarah Ruthers#6'
output = re.sub("[^\\w]", "", s)

print output
```

The above removes ALL alpha characters; I simply want to remove any characters after the last alpha (letter type character); or trailing last alpha character for instance.

*i.e.* `Sarah Ruthers#6`

to output simply:

```
Sarah Ruthers
```

My regex above; outputs `SarahRuthers` (removing the space)

Comment: Your regex would not do what you claim, it would output `SarahRuthers6` (because `6` is a "word character"; `\w` includes letters, digits and the underscore character).

Answer (score 2):

Anchor your pattern at the end, and use a correct character class:

```
output = re.sub(r"[\W\d_]+$", "", s)
```

That'll remove a single run of all non-letter characters at the end of the string; the `$` anchor limits the range, and `[\W\d_]` properly matches non-letters, not just non-word characters (word characters include digits and the underscore character).

I also made the regex a raw string (which you should always do anyway for regex patterns), removing the need to double the backslashes.

Note that while `[^a-zA-Z]` could replace `[\W\d_]` for your specific case, I strongly recommend `[\W\d_]` over `[^a-zA-Z]` because the former is Unicode friendly, while the latter is not; for example if your text is `'résumé'`, using `[^a-zA-Z]` will strip the trailing `é`, `[\W\d_]` won't.

Answer (score 1):

```
output = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]+$", "", s)
```

Comment: ++ but better you make it `re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]+$", "", s`

Comment: Note: This solution is not Unicode friendly, as it will treat non-ASCII letters as non-letters. I suggested `[\W\d_]` in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57434010/364696) for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

`\w` is "word character" which includes alphanumeric (letters, numbers) plus underscore (_).

Say that you only need to retain uppercase and lowercase letters towards the end:

```
output = re.sub("[^A-Za-z ]+$", "", s)
```